# Function works every other time it is called

Tags: arduino, serial-port, buffer

My following function reads from a serial port, processes the data and displays info to the user. the interesting thing is that it seems to only work when called on odd numbered instances. On even reads, the timeout case occurs.

This function is called every 10sec or sooner if called by the user. No matter how often it's called it will work every other time.

CODE:

```
bool SR(bool echo, int&value)
{ 
  bool valid;
  byte buf [2];
```

on even calls `red` returns `0`

```
  byte red = Serial2.readBytes(buf,2);
  if(red>0)
  {
```

Here is the "good data" case `SvAdd` gives me the sender address while `FCode` gives the type of message sent (there are 8 types of messages, but we're only using types 3 and 6)

```
    valid=true;
    byte SvAdd = buf[0];
    byte FCode = buf[1];
    int Read;
    byte registerL;
    switch (FCode)
    {
      case 3:
```

Data for case 3 (read-only) appears as shown in this table:
[image: Case 3 Data]

```
        Serial2.readBytes(buf,1);
        registerL = buf[0];
        for (byte i=(registerL/2); i>0 ; i--)
        {
          Serial2.readBytes(buf,2);
          Read = buf[1] | buf[0] << 8;
        }
```

For now, `registerL` **should** always be `2` however I added the loop just in case

```
        value=Read;
        break;
      case 6:
```

Data for case 6 (write then read) appears as shown in this table:
[image: case 6 Write -> read]

```
        Serial2.readBytes(buf,2);
        Read = buf[1] | buf[0] << 8;
        Serial2.readBytes(buf,2);
        Read = buf[1] | buf[0] << 8;
        value=Read;
```

I know the address so I read past it and only look at the data bits to verify the correct function was written

```
        break; 
    }
```

Aquire the last two CRC bytes from the function (to clear the buffer)

```
    Serial2.readBytes(buf,2);
    int CRC = buf[1] | buf[0] << 8;
    if (echo)
    {
      Serial.println(SvAdd);
      Serial.println(FCode);
      switch (FCode)
      {
        case 3:
          Serial.println(registerL);
          Serial.println(Read);   //Last Value read
          break;
        case 6:
          Serial.println(Read);   //Value
          break; 
      }
      Serial.println(CRC);
    }
    return valid;
  }
```

---

**Here is the case when `red=0`**

```
  else
  {
    valid=false;   
    Serial.println("timeout");
    return valid;
  }
}
```

---

**EDIT** (contiguous code)

```
bool SR(bool echo, int&value)
{ 
  bool valid;
  byte buf [2];
  byte red = Serial2.readBytes(buf,2);
  if(red>0)
  {
    valid=true;
    byte SvAdd = buf[0];
    byte FCode = buf[1];
    int Read;
    byte registerL;
    switch (FCode)
    {
      case 3:
        Serial2.readBytes(buf,1);
        registerL = buf[0];
        for (byte i=(registerL/2); i>0 ; i--)
        {
          Serial2.readBytes(buf,2);
          Read = buf[1] | buf[0] << 8;
        }
        value=Read;
        break;
      case 6:
        Serial2.readBytes(buf,2);
        Read = buf[1] | buf[0] << 8;
        Serial2.readBytes(buf,2);
        Read = buf[1] | buf[0] << 8;
        value=Read;
        break; 
    }
    Serial2.readBytes(buf,2);
    int CRC = buf[1] | buf[0] << 8;
    if (echo)
    {
      Serial.println(SvAdd);
      Serial.println(FCode);
      switch (FCode)
      {
        case 3:
          Serial.println(registerL);
          Serial.println(Read);   //Last Value read
          break;
        case 6:
          Serial.println(Read);   //Value
          break; 
      }
      Serial.println(CRC);
    }
    return valid;
  }
  else
  {
    valid=false;   
    Serial.println("timeout");
    return valid;
  }
}
```

Comment: It would be much easier to examine your code if it were posted as a single contiguous block, instead of pieces.

Comment: Sorry, editing now

Comment: @TomServo Contiguous block created and added to the end

Answer (score 1):

One thing I see is that `Read` is defined as `int` i.e. signed int.  I wonder if you'd get better results, since you're creating it through bit-shifting, if you'd define it as `unsigned int`.  If you shift a `1` into that MSB position, all of a sudden (as an `int`) **`Read` is a negative number.**

Next:

```
Read = buf[1] | buf[0] << 8;
Serial2.readBytes(buf,2);
Read = buf[1] | buf[0] << 8;
value=Read;
```

You realize that `Read` is being assigned twice consecutively, right?  So it will retain only the last value.  That's okay if you want to discard the transmitted address.  But it doesn't look like you do, because of this:

```
Serial.println(Read);   //Addr
Serial.println(Read);   //Value
```

`Read` is not both the address and the value.

I suggest you look into those two fishy items first.  I can't run your code right now, but a closer look at these items might shed light on your issue.

Finally, your function call itself, if you want to pass a pointer in, should read:

```
bool SR(bool echo, unsigned int * value)
```

But the bottom line is that if you're getting "timeout" every other time, it's because `red` is NOT > 0, and the `readBytes` statement just above didn't work.

Comment: I do realize the consecutive assignment, for right now I don't care about the transmitted address. (whoops I missed that) I have two questions: 1) I do work with negative numbers being received by the device, if I make `Read` unsigned how would I get the unsigned int back to being an int (can I just `(int)Read` it?) 2) Any idea why `red=0` every other time the function is called? there should be serial data there as it only occurs after a write